# Consecutive indexing in Python - as opposed to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, indexing

I have a 1680 x 8 dimensional features.mat array.
In a loop in Matlab, I extracted in each iteration the consecutive 120 rows, with this (snippet of the code):

```
for k = 1:14

    features = features(1+(k-1)*60:60*(k+1),:);
    % some other code
end
```

Now I am new to python, and not sure about indexing. Having loaded the .mat file as a numpy array, I see that indexing starts at 0 - but if I loop from 0 to 119, it throws an error saying that these would be only 119 rows - why is that, and how then do I have to write the above loop in python?

Comment: Matlab arrays starts at index: 1. Numpy arrays starts at 0. Could that be what's causing your issue?

Comment: Yes I get that, and as mentioned I start at 0 with indexing - but then, to get 120 elements that should be 0 to 119 - but python forces me to extract rows 0 - 120 which are 121 rows - except I am missing something?

Comment: The end index of the range type is exclusive: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Comment: Can we see your python code?

Do you loop through your list like this: for item in list: ?

Comment: exclusive end explains it! Many thanks @atn